# How to handle with GridView distance between images?

Tags: android, gridview

I want to create app like on galaxy 4s to send to a group contacts.
the group contact names show in a gridView. the problem is when i add new names the distance between them is by column .i what the distance will be more flexible for different length of names like in the example :

[image]

[image]

my code:
Main.xml

```
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridNames"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit" >

    </GridView>
```

row_grid.xml

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/grid_rowName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/round_shape"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:text="Anna 123"
    android:textSize="17dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Thanks!

Comment: you can set the numof colums ..All i know to display 3 or two in a row

Comment: I know but i can't know how many columns i will need because the names has different length...

Comment: Don't use a `GridView`, that's not really what you want. Instead you should use something like a FlowLayout(there are several implementation around the web), a layout that works as a horizontal `LinearLayout` which puts any child who doesn't fit the current row below, on another row.